# principle about SPAD for ToF ranging module from ST

Tags: photodiode, optics

My colleagues are using VL53L0 from ST which is one ToF ranging module. I am trying to understand the principle about the SPAD(single-photon avalanche diode) and have read many materials on it.

From one paper, it reads ***the output of a SPAD is an electrical pulse for each detected photon***. Does it mean that the reflected photon won't arrive simultaneously? How much is the interval between arrival of two sequential photons? Can the digital circuitry detect the arrival interval?

Answer (score 1):

When a single photon hits the photodiode (and is converted), it will avalanche, making a big signal that the logic can see, very quickly.

It will then be blind to subsequent photons.

This is OK, the chip is going to average a huge number of repeats.

These chips arrived on sale years after there were prototypes, I suspect it was a harder trick to actually get working.